# Force fully qualified names for EF core migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When creating an EF migration I'm getting ambiguous references:

> PostgreSQLDBContextModelSnapshot.cs(32,32): Error CS0104: 'Metadata' is an ambiguous reference between 'Data.Models.Metadata' and 'Data.Paths.Metadata'

I have tried to fully qualify `MetaData` in my model object but without success. I could fix the auto generated snapshot but that feels wrong.

Is there a way to force EF to use fully qualified names?

Comment: Have you tried aliasing them? For example something like: `using dm = Data.Models.Metadata;` and `using p = Data.Paths.Metadata;`; then use the alias...

Comment: Alias them where? In my models? Or in the snapshot?

Comment: In your models..

Comment: No, haven't. Unfortunately, the models are auto generated, too. So any change in there could be lost. Even it works...I'll try still.

Comment: Suggested aliasing in models is not helping. Generated migration still uses original simple class names which produces described naming conflict.